# How to implement a horizontal RecyclerView inside another vertical RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to put a horizontal RecyclerView(**InnerRecyclerView**) inside another vertical RecyclerView(**OuterRecyclerView**) and parse data into it after two separate volley calls. I was able to successfully parse the data to the vertical RecyclerView after the first webservice call. Now I'm trying to put the data from the second webservice into the horizontal RecyclerView.

For this I have implemented two seperate RecyclerView adapter classes. What I don't understand is how to define the InnerRecyclerView in the OuterRecyclerView and make the whole thing work together by passing data from the second web service call like I did in the first. I'm a beginner with this, I appreciate your help.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RequestQueue requestQueue ;
RequestQueue requestQueue2 ;

RecyclerView recyclerView;

RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;
List<OuterDataModel> DataAdapterClassList;
List<InnerOuterDataModel> InnerAdapterClassList;
LinearLayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
public String callIdForParse;
OuterDataModel GetOuterDataModel = new OuterDataModel();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    DataAdapterClassList = new ArrayList<>();


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);

    recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);

    myurl  = "http://pastebin.com/START";


    OuterWebCall();

//Some actions then  I call the second webservice

    InnerWebCall();


}



  public void OuterWebCall(){

    String HTTP_SERVER_URL= String.format("http://pastebin.com/mySampleApi/student/%1$s",mStudentRoll);
    JsonArrayRequest jsArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, HTTP_SERVER_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());

                    AfterOuterWebCall(response);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Hello");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            }){

    };
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsArrRequest);
}



public void AfterOuterWebCall(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        OuterDataModel GetOuterDataModel = new OuterDataModel();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            GetOuterDataModel.setId(json.getString("CLASS"));
            GetOuterDataModel.setPlateNo(json.getString("HOUSE"));
            GetOuterDataModel.setPlateCode(json.getString("IMAGEURL"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            DataAdapterClassList.add(GetOuterDataModel);
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    if (array.length() != 0) {
    recyclerViewadapter = new NewRecyclerViewAdapter(DataAdapterClassList, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
}

public void InnerWebCall(){

    String HTTP_SERVER_URL= String.format("http://192.1.2.2/test");

    JsonArrayRequest jsArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, HTTP_SERVER_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());

                    AfterInnerWebCall(response);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Hello");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }){

    };


    requestQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue2.add(jsArrRequest);


}



public void AfterInnerWebCall (JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

        InnerOuterDataModel GetInnerOuterDataModel = new InnerOuterDataModel();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            GetInnerOuterDataModel.setName(json.getString("Name"));

            GetInnerOuterDataModel.setRank(json.getString("Rank"));

            GetInnerOuterDataModel.setPerId(json.getString("ID"));


        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        InnerAdapterClassList.add(GetInnerOuterDataModel);


    }
    if (array.length() != 0) {

       // How to pass the data to the InnerRecyclerViewAdapter?

    }
}

}
```

**OuterRecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class OuterRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OuterRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;

public List<DataModel> dataModels;

public List<PersonnelOnDutyDataModel> dataModels2;

public int mExpandedPosition=-1;


public OuterRecyclerViewAdapter(List<DataModel> getDataAdapter, Context context){

    super();
    this.dataModels = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;

}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    DataModel dataAdapter =  dataModels.get(position);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);

    viewHolder.InnerRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

    viewHolder.class.setText(dataAdapter.getClass());

    viewHolder.house.setText(dataAdapter.getHouse());

    //Glide.with(context).load(dataAdapter.getImgUrl()).into(viewHolder.imageView)



    final boolean isExpanded = position==mExpandedPosition;
   // viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(isExpanded?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
    viewHolder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:position;
            //TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return dataModels.size();
}



class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView class;
    public TextView house;
    public ImageView imageView;
    private RecyclerView InnerRecyclerView;
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;



    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        InnerRecyclerView= (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.innerRecyclerView);

        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        class=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewClass);
        house=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHouse);
        constraintLayout=(ConstraintLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.constrainLayout);

    }
}
}
```

**InnerRecyclerView.java**

```
public class InnerRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InnerRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;

public List<InnerDataModel> dataModels;

public InnerRecyclerViewAdapter(List<InnerDataModel> getDataAdapter, Context context){

    super();

    this.dataModels = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;
}

public int mExpandedPosition=-1;

@Override
public InnerRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.personnel_on_duty_card, parent, false);

    InnerRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new InnerRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final InnerRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    InnerDataModel dataAdapter =  dataModels.get(position);

    viewHolder.NameStudentCard.setText(dataAdapter.getName());

    viewHolder.RankCard.setText(dataAdapter.getRank());

    viewHolder.IDCard.setText(dataAdapter.getId());

    final boolean isExpanded = position==mExpandedPosition;

    viewHolder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:position;
            //TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return dataModels.size();
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView NameStudentCard;
    public TextView RankCard;
    public TextView IDCard;
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        NameStudentCard=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNameInCard);
        RankCard=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewrankInCard);
        IDCard =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.IDInCard);
        constraintLayout=(ConstraintLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.constrainLayout);

    }
}

}
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
sothree:umanoFadeColor="@android:color/transparent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:text=" Sliding Up Panel"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:id="@+id/dragView">



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

**OuterRecyclerView.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/CardViewOuter"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
app:cardElevation="2dp"
android:transitionName="weatherCardTransition"
>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constrainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewStatus"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewStatus">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewClass"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Class"
        android:textColor="@color/card_text_primary"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/card_header_status"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewCalass" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="352dp"
        android:layout_height="134dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/innerRecyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewCalass" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**InnerCard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cardViewInnerCard"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
app:cardElevation="2dp"
android:transitionName="weatherCardTransition"
>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNameInCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewrankInCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewNameInCard" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/IDInCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewrankInCard" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your item xml of both?

Comment: @New Coder by analogy, is the very same problem of a matrix, which you would represent in any language as an array of array ... so instead of having mDataset[], you will have mDataset[][] ... the first iteration over it (you outer recycler view) will give you the rows, each of which is mDataset[], which you will pass over, and then you'll have the second iteration over each row (your inner recycler view) that will give you each item data set to bind to the view, per each row

Comment: @Alessio could you please explain it to me in my code?

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån xml files are added

Comment: Initialise your inner adapter in the onBindViewHolder of the outer adapter, the same way you initialised the outer adapter in the activity.

Comment: @CoolGuyCG ok. after that how shall I pass the data from mainactivity after the second webcall to the inner adapter?

Comment: @CoolGuyCG could you pleas explain it in the code provided, I'm new to this topic

Comment: @NewCoder I'm so sorry I don't have the time to make your homework, and the code you pasted is too overwhelming that I don't have the time to go through it all. What I wrote should be enough to get you running. Do it by small steps: first implement only the vertical part (1 degree array), have 1 item for each row; only then add the 1 more degree complexity, adding the row loop. Of course you can also go the other way around: first implement 1 row working, and then add the vertical loop.

Comment: @NewCoder, I won't advise that you do it the way you intend to do it, that is, a Vertical List with a horizontal list in it. I suggest you rather use a vertical LinearLayout whose parent is a ScrollView and then add your horizontal list to a view that will then be added to your LinearLayout.